# Mostrar un decimal con punto como separador de miles y coma para separar dos decimales

Tags: c#

Pues esto es lo que me está quebrando la cabeza. Estoy desarrollando en C#. Los datos vienen de una consulta hecha a una tabla de sql server, los paso a un dataGridView y en un evento doubleClick los mando a los textbox correspondientes, previo intentar darles el formato que describo en el título. Tengo cargado en el frmPrincipal y antes de inicializar los componentes, lo siguiente:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-AR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
```

La salida que obtengo es `30000.00` cuando lo que pretendo es `30.000,00`.

Probé `String.Format("{0:###.##0,00}"`,... y `{0:n}` y siempre obtengo el mismo resultado
Alguna ayuda o idea de que me está faltando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar utilizando `NumberFormatInfo`.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal numero = 300000.23M;

        NumberFormatInfo formato = new CultureInfo("es-AR").NumberFormat;

        formato.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
        formato.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

        //puedes cambiar el simbolo $ por otro.
        //formato.CurrencySymbol = "$";

        Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("C", formato));
        Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("N", formato));
    }
}
```

La salida del mismo es:

```
$ 300.000,23 //C: de Moneda
300.000,23   //N: de Numero
```

> [NumberFormatInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2): Proporciona información de formato específica de la referencia cultural y los valores numéricos de análisis.
>
> [CurrencyGroupSeparator](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupseparator?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo_CurrencyGroupSeparator): Obtiene o establece la cadena que separa grupos de dígitos a la izquierda de la coma decimal en valores de divisa.
>
> [Especificador de formato](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2): Las cadenas de formato numérico estándar se utilizan para dar formato a tipos numéricos comunes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Orlando, el ejemplo funciona perfectamente así como la adaptación del mismo.